# error bars on facet_grid with multiple groups

Tags: r, ggplot2

Does anyone know why the error-bars are being placed on top of each other and not grouped based on `variable` ? Dont mind the dulpcated columns in my data.

```
> head(dual_average_sd)
            siRNA Time variable   average           siRNA variable          sd
1 Fluc-3-x-Bp3Mid    2 Avg100nM 1.1360882 Fluc-3-x-Bp3Mid Std100nM 0.380483728
2 Fluc-3-x-Bp3Mid    4 Avg100nM 1.0289251 Fluc-3-x-Bp3Mid Std100nM 0.206174705
3 Fluc-3-x-Bp3Mid    6 Avg100nM 0.8314746 Fluc-3-x-Bp3Mid Std100nM 0.053001934
4 Fluc-3-x-Bp3Mid   12 Avg100nM 0.7197690 Fluc-3-x-Bp3Mid Std100nM 0.008183043
5 Fluc-3-x-Bp3Mid   24 Avg100nM 0.4688671 Fluc-3-x-Bp3Mid Std100nM 0.015459736
6 Fluc-3-x-Bp3Mid   48 Avg100nM 0.4912145 Fluc-3-x-Bp3Mid Std100nM 0.038062323

p <- ggplot(dual_average_sd, aes(x=siRNA, y=average, fill=variable)) + geom_bar(stat="identity",position = "dodge") + 
  theme_bw() + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)) + facet_grid(~Time) 

p + geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=average-sd, ymax=average+sd
  ),width=.3, position=position_dodge(0.05)) +  
  labs(x="Time (h)", y="FLuc/RLuc") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)) + facet_grid(~Time)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to increase the value for `position_dodge()`, e.g.:

```
geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=average-sd, ymax=average+sd),
width=.3, 
position=position_dodge(1))
```